# Laravel Dusk running in Ubuntu 20.04 Error Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally

Tags: laravel, google-chrome, laravel-dusk

When I run

```
$ php artisan  dusk tests/Browser/ExampleTest.php
```

It prompt the error

> 1. Tests\Browser\ExampleTest::testExample
>    Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownServerException: unknown error:
>    Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally   (unknown error:
>    DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)   (The process started from
>    chrome location /snap/bin/chromium is no longer running, so
>    ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)   (Driver info:
>    chromedriver=2.45.615279
>    (12b89733300bd268cff3b78fc76cb8f3a7cc44e5),platform=Linux
>    5.4.0-107-generic x86_64)

I check the chrome driver, it is install correctly.

```
$ php artisan dusk:chrome-driver
```

> ChromeDriver binary successfully installed for version 100.0.4896.60.

Then I google the error. They said to check the chrome version

```
$ /usr/bin/chromium-browser --version
```

> /usr/bin/chromium-browser: 12: xdg-settings: not found cannot create
> user data directory: /home/shiro/snap/chromium/1952: Permission
> denied

My goal is need to run Laravel Dusk in Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Make sure your `chromium-browser` need to REMOVE and INSTALL snap stable version MATCH with your **Laravel Dusk Chrome Driver**

Below is the step, I run:-

Next fix the Chromium issue by install via snap, then next error

```
$ sudo snap refresh --edge chromium
```

> error: cannot communicate with server: Post
> http://localhost/v2/snaps/chromium: dial unix /run/snapd.socket:
> connect: no such file or directory

to solve the error, need to update the packages.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:saiarcot895/chromium-beta
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

Finally, it show the version. However, does not match my Laravel Chrome driver. Didn't solve my first issue. Still can't run `dusk`

```
$ /usr/bin/chromium-browser --version
Chromium 97.0.4692.20 Ubuntu 20.04
```

Next install `snap` version of Chrome and remove the `chromium-browser`

```
$ systemctl start snapd.service
$ sudo snap install chromium
$ sudo apt remove chromium-browser
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE**

$ /usr/bin/chromium-browser --version
-bash: /usr/bin/chrome: No such file or directory

Boom~ It works~